# All possible numbers from a keypad

Tags: algorithm, graph

I'm trying to solve this problem:

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
*  0  #
```

Given a starting number, find all 6-digit numbers possible, numbers can only be dialed horizontally or vertically. Repetitions not allowed. Number can't start from zero and doesn't include * and #. For example, if last dialed number is 3, the next one could be 1, 2, 6 or 9.

I'm trying this making by creating a graph, in which a number has only those numbers adjacent which are in the same row and column, and then finding all possible paths of length 5 from the starting number. But I don't know any algorithm for doing that yet..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume the numbers are stored in a 2-d array `NUMPAD`, where "1" is at index [0][0], "2" is at index [0][1], etc.

```
Func permute_nums(digits_so_far)
    If digits_so_far has 6 elements
        print digits_so_far
        return
    Let L = last element of digits_so_far
    Find index (x,y) of L in NUMPAD
    For i from -2 to +2
        if (x+i,y) is NOT out of bounds
            Find number n at (x+i,y)
            permute_nums(digits_so_far + [n])
        if (x,y+i) is NOT out of bounds
            Find number m at (x,y+i)
            permute_nums(digits_so_far + [m])
```

Given the starting digit `s`, do `permute_nums([s])`

Comment: "out of bounds" = either outside of NUMPAD, or corresponds to * or #

Comment: I assumed that "no repetitions" only means that the same digit can't appear twice in succession (e.g. 122345 is bad, but 123245 is okay). If every digit of the 6-digit number has to be unique, then besides the "out of bounds" check, we also need to check that the number n (or m) is not already in digits_so_far.

Comment: But won't the size of digits_so_far grow indefinitely? Isn't it required to remove elements once it has 6 digits?

Comment: No, it's recursive, and at the top of the function you'll see that it stops recursing once it hits 6 digits. The for loop takes care of iterating over all possible 2nd digits, then (one level of recursion later) all possible 3rd digits, etc.

Comment: I said that because I am using a pointer to the array digits_so_far, and an integer for its size, so recursion doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Will decreasing the size variable by 1 just after the two recursive calls do it? Or is there a better way?

Comment: In that case, the algorithm would have to be modified to take in `d`, the number of digits computed so far, which increments by 1 on each recursive call. The last "valid" digit on each recursive step is `arr[d-1]`, and before moving to the next recursive step, you would set the value of `arr[d]` to be `n` (or `m`)

Comment: Thanks man, that helped a lot. The only problem is that it generates lots of duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right path.
Just traverse the tree (mark every visited node, to avoid repetitions), and output every path of length 5.

You don't really need anything new here, even a basic [Breadth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal#Breadth-first_search) that is limited to depth 5 will do.

Answer (score 0):

hmmm. That should be pretty easy.

```
static var a:Array=[[8],[2,4],[1,3,5],[2,6],[1,5,7],[2,4,6,8],[3,5,9],[4,8],[5,7,9,0],[6,8]];
function giveAllnumbers(numbersSoFar:String,lastSelectedNumber:int,:int) {
    if (howManyToSelectLeft==0) {
        trace(numbersSoFar); // output goes here
        return;
    }
    for (var i:int=a[lastSelectedNumber].length-1;i>=0;i--) 
        giveAllNumbers(numbersSoFar+a[lastSelectedNumber][i].toString(),
            a[lastSelectedNumber][i],
            howManyToSelectLeft-1);
}
```

This is Actionscript, but can be accommodated to any other language. Invoke with `giveAllNumbers(''+yourNumber.toString(),yourNumber,desiredLength);`

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved recursively, and the returning point will be when length == 6.

```
private static void countMaxNumbers(String i) {
    if(i.length() == 6)
    {
        numberCount++;
        return;
    }
    if(i.charAt(i.length() - 1) == '1'){
        countMaxNumbers(i+'2');
        countMaxNumbers(i+'3');
        countMaxNumbers(i+'4');
        countMaxNumbers(i+'7');
    }
    else if(i.charAt(i.length() - 1) == '2'){
        countMaxNumbers(i+'5');
        countMaxNumbers(i+'8');
        countMaxNumbers(i+'0');
        countMaxNumbers(i+'1');
        countMaxNumbers(i+'3');
    }
    else if(i.charAt(i.length() - 1) == '3'){
        countMaxNumbers(i+'1');
        countMaxNumbers(i+'2');
        countMaxNumbers(i+'6');
        countMaxNumbers(i+'9');
    }
    else if(i.charAt(i.length() - 1) == '4'){
        countMaxNumbers(i+'1');
        countMaxNumbers(i+'7');
        countMaxNumbers(i+'5');
        countMaxNumbers(i+'6');
    }
    else if(i.charAt(i.length() - 1) == '5'){
        countMaxNumbers(i+'2');
        countMaxNumbers(i+'8');
        countMaxNumbers(i+'0');
        countMaxNumbers(i+'4');
        countMaxNumbers(i+'6');
    }
    else if(i.charAt(i.length() - 1) == '6'){
        countMaxNumbers(i+'3');
        countMaxNumbers(i+'9');
        countMaxNumbers(i+'4');
        countMaxNumbers(i+'5');

    }
    else if(i.charAt(i.length() - 1) == '7'){
        countMaxNumbers(i+'1');
        countMaxNumbers(i+'4');
        countMaxNumbers(i+'8');
        countMaxNumbers(i+'9');

    }else if(i.charAt(i.length() - 1) == '8'){
        countMaxNumbers(i+'7');
        countMaxNumbers(i+'9');
        countMaxNumbers(i+'2');
        countMaxNumbers(i+'5');
        countMaxNumbers(i+'0');
    }else if(i.charAt(i.length() - 1) == '9'){
        countMaxNumbers(i+'3');
        countMaxNumbers(i+'6');
        countMaxNumbers(i+'7');
        countMaxNumbers(i+'8');
    }else if(i.charAt(i.length() - 1) == '0'){
        countMaxNumbers(i+'2');
        countMaxNumbers(i+'8');
        countMaxNumbers(i+'5');
    }
}
```

Answer should be : 12855